# Python требует расширение для отладки Hack Configurations . Маркет выкладывает кучу дополнений по запросу, но которое из них то, что нужно, не ясно.

Tags: python, файлы

Я пытаюсь запустить программу. Python сообщает: " У вас нет расширения для отладки Hack Configurations. Найти расширение Hack Configurations в Marketplace?" Я соглашаюсь и на панели расширений появляется куча новых расширений с опциями "установить". Но какое из них то, что нужно, по названию не понятно. Слова Hack в названиях нет. Что это за проблема и как ее решить?

Comment: Python не может ничего требовать и в нём в принципе нет никакого Marketplace, так что непонятно о чём тут речь вообще

Comment: Прислать скриншот?

Comment: Панели, расширения, маркет....все указывает на vs code, о котором в вопросе ни слова. hack указывает на расширение  vscode-hack, только причем тут вообще питон. Будем ждать телепатов

Comment: Ну, да, это интерпретатор Visual Studio Code , а прога на Python . И другие программы запускаются без проблем. Отличие этой - в ней есть предложения на русском языке., типа "Введите значение ...". Проблема может быть в этом?

Answer (score 0):

Проблема решилась след. образом.

Файл, на который ругалась *VScode* был скопирован из PDF файла. Нужно было перед запуском сохранить программу с расширением .py. Текст сразу стал подкрашиваться и программа ожила.